# Radio buttons in configuration are not horizontal

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4, configuration, ui-form

I am working on the magento configuration and I am using the radio buttons and it is working well. The issue is that I cannot add them inline but only vertical. Is there a solution for it ?

```
   <field id="something_id" translate="label" type="radios" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
               showInStore="0">
            <label>Enable logging</label>
            <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
            <config_path>vendor/abstract/logging</config_path>
            <tooltip>
                <![CDATA[Enable log mode]]></tooltip>
        </field>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there , you can add CSS class to it by _module.less in your module in adminhtml directory.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I already added `view/adminhtml/web/styles.css` could I use this or it should be specific `_module.less`? How could I use it ?

Comment: Yes it should be more specific in your module and this should be file path = view/adminhtml/web/css/source/_module.less , if this answer helped you please do give a like as this helps me asnwer more.Thanks.

Comment: any idea how the css should be ? the html is as follows
```
<input type="radio" 
name="groups[group_all_in_one][groups][settings][fields][debug][value]" value="1" 
class="admin__control-radio" 
id="settings_debug1">
```